# Json Parsing using python for values with comma separated

Tags: python, json

I have below sample json file . I am trying to do parsing using python .

```
[{
  "ID":123,
  "Project":"testing",
  "Script":"script-1,script-2",
  "Status":"present"
}]
```

I have using below python script :

```
import json
with open('project.json', 'r') as f:
  project_details = json.load(f)
 
for project in project_details:
  print("ID=",project['ID'],',', "ProjectName=",project['Project'],',', "Scripts=",project['Script'],',',)
```

I am getting below output

```
ID= 123 , ProjectName= testing , Scripts= script-1,scrip-2 ,
```

But I want below output

```
ID= 123 , ProjectName= testing , Scripts= script ,
```

Comment: you get `script-1,scrip-2` because the `project['Script']` contains that, to get just `script`, you can use slicing as `project['Script'][:6]`.

Comment: You have a couple of errors in the posted code. ie, project_details are not defined, also the Json code is missing a period in "Script". Can you correct this?

Comment: Thanks Krishna, That helped .

Comment: you can also use  `project['Script'].split(",")[0]`